# Flight Schedule DB Model SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design

I am trying to create a DB model in SQL Server for storing Flight schedules (not real time), i have finally come up with 2 DB model but confused, which one to choose to store the schedules.

Approach:1
For each flight, store the schedules in the same column (123X56X) along with flight name, depart time, arrival time, source, destination. (123X56X) It means that particular flight is available on Sunday(1), Monday(2), Tuesday(3), Thursday(5) and Friday(6)

Approach:2
Keep the flight name, depart time, arrival time, source, destination in one table and create a new mapping table for schedules.

Table1 - wk_days

```
wk_day_id   wk_day_short     wk_day_long
1              Sun             Sunday
2              Mon             Monday
```

Table2 - flight_schedule

```
flight_sch_id   flight_id   src_city_id dest_city_id    Depart_tm   Arrival_tm  Duration
1                 1           1            2              6:00        8:00        2:00
```

Table3 - flight_schedule_wk_days

```
flight_sch_id   wk_day_id   
1                  2           
1                  3
1                  4
2                  2
2                  3
2                  4
```

Please suggest, which one is better?

Comment: Approach #2 is better. That idea for #1 is denormalized and will cause you lots of pain in the future.

Comment: Thank you for the comments Sean. I too vote for Approach #2 but my colleagues were confused me little on this, so want to get it clarified with experts.

Comment: heh not sure about the experts part but you did get an opinion from me. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A flight schedule database is actually quite a bit more complicated in the real world than either of your examples.  (More on this in a moment.)

**To answer your question:** In general the normalized database approach is a better idea, especially for a transactional database.  The second design is normalized.  Your first option is reminiscent of old COBOL flat file systems like the original SABRE system.

Using a normalized approach makes your queries much easier and more efficient.  Finding out which flights fly on a Tuesday means scanning and doing an in-string analysis on every record under option 1.  In option 2 your database can use an index to answer this question without having to read and analyze each record.

On a broader note, a flight is not just an origin and a destination at a particular time on some set of days of the week.  Here are some things that a real-world flight schedule database needs to be able to handle:

- Flights have an airline identifier
- Flights have an operator airline, which can be different from the seller (i.e. "code-share")
- Flights can have multiple legs (i.e. multiple sets of origins and destinations under one number)
- Flights as defined by scheduling systems do have days of the week, like your model, but they also need to have a start date and end date for the date range in which the flight will operate.

Depending on what your application is intended to do, you might need to take some or all of these into account.

Comment: Thanks very much for the detailed comments. My application is an Intranet Flight Travel approval system. User requests for travel and it goes to several approvals before reaching to Travel Desk to confirm the flight booking. Users are allowed to choose the available flight schedules during request that we need to get it from database.

Comment: Moreover, I realized the complicated on designing the database model for maintaining the schedules and that too maintaining in schedules in own server will costs additional services to load the real time flight schedules, for ex, user can choose a travel date upto 4 months, ex: user can choose till 12 Jan, 2015, when requests for today.  I have also looked at the google's api https://developers.google.com/qpx-express/. Any thoughts on using this api for real time schedules and just storing the selected flight details in the database rather maintaining all schedules all year

Comment: @Maneshwar - Thank you for explaining more about your system.  I would suggest in your case flight _schedule_ is actually not what you're interested in, but rather, flight _bookings_.  If you have ready access to a 3rd party schedule (by API or database) that maintains the very complex and dynamic flight schedule data, then you just need to store the _instance_ of a flight that requires review and approval.  This should simplify your model considerably.

Comment: Yes, it is true, decided to use 3rd party API for flight schedules. :-). Thanks very much for all your valuable inputs.